# ElasticSearch :Need to add a dynamic field which can store empty array,values as well as json object inside the field

Tags: elasticsearch

I need a field in index where we can add any types of data. I mean we need to add json objects , empty array and empty values as well as any type of values to the field.

Please let me know if there is any way to achieve this in elastic search.

Field: data :{
"fname":"abc",
""lname:"xyz"
}

Field : data :["",""]
field : data :"abc"

I want to store all above mentioned values in data field.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `flattened` datatype in elasticsearch https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/flattened.html